# Install Bootstrap-Vue from Git with npm

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to install the current GIT version of the bootstrap-vue package (`https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue`).

I was able to install it with npm from github.com. But if I try to import it then it is not working because there is no dist folder.

What is the correct way to install packages from github directly?

**SOLVED**

What I want is not possible. You have to clone the repository and run the build script (/scripts/build.sh/)

Comment: for `bootstrap-vue` u need to install both `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-vue` further details can be found here https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs,  use this commad `npm i vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap --save`

Comment: I want to install the last git version. Not the npm version. (And yes, bootstrap 4.3.1 is also installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a github repo branch as a dependancy in package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue#dev"
  }
}
```

This will add the dev branch as a dependency.

But you will still need to build BootstrapVue once you run `yarn install` (or similar for `npm`).  Once installed, cd into `node_modules/bootstrap-vue` and run `yarn install && yarn build` to build BootstrapVue's `/dist` and `/es` directories.  Once built, then you can CD back up to your project and run your project build.